# Why can't NumRewriteThreads and NumExpensiveRewriteThreads be used with Nginx PageSpeed?

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

So I was trying some settings of the Nginx PageSpeed module, but there was two settings that I couldn't set for some reason.

```
pagespeed NumRewriteThreads 2;
pagespeed NumExpensiveRewriteThreads 2;
```

For some reason these two settings always throw error when I try to restart or test my nginx config.

```
sudo service nginx restart
[FAIL] Restarting nginx: nginx failed!
```

When I test the file I get this:

```
"pagespeed" directive "NumRewriteThreads" not recognized or too many arguments in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My Nginx version is the following:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.6.0
```

The settings appear in the PageSpeed docs as well, so I'm wondering if there's something I am missing to make them work.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#tune_thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've entered a bug for this: [ngx_pagespeed #728](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/728).  I think it's just an oversight.